# Google keeps redirecting me to the old OAuth2 callback url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm using `gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'`. I can't authenticate at google because it says the callback url is different from the one I've set at google console for the project.

```
#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

#config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.configuration.google_analytics = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'google_analytics.yml'))[Rails.env]
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(:google_oauth2, Rails.configuration.google_analytics['client_id'], Rails.configuration.google_analytics['client_secret'], 
    { scope: 'userinfo.profile, userinfo.email, analytics', access_type: 'offline', prompt: 'consent' }
  )
end


# app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    #.....
```

Response details from google:

```
    from_login=1
    response_type=code
    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics
    access_type=offline
    redirect_uri=http://my_app.herokuapp.com/users/oauth/google_oauth2/callback
    state=fsfdsfds
    as=-fdsfds
    pli=1
    client_id=fdsfds-fdsfdsfd.apps.googleusercontent.com
    prompt=consent
    authuser=1
    hl=en
```

So the problem is the callback url at google console is set to `http://my_app.herokuapp.com/users/omniauth_callbacks/google_oauth2` and in the application according to all the setting is it's the same, but google keeps redirecting me to `http://my_app.herokuapp.com/users/oauth/google_oauth2/callback` for some reason.

Comment: what you call "Response details from google" are actually the parameters that you send as part of the authorization request *to* Google so I guess your application settings are off

Comment: @HansZ, all right, but how can they be off, what did I do wrong?